# change locale grouping

Tags: locale

I use el_GR.UTF-8 which does not group thousands. I changed /usr/share/i18n/locales/el_GR, updated:

```
sudo locale-gen el_GR
sudo locale-gen el_GR.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LANG=el_GR.UTF-8
```

but still printf "%'.1f\n" 1000 produces
1000,0
instead of 1.000,0

Comment: ubuntu 16.04, cinnamon 3

Answer (score 1):

Do not modify files that are manged by your distribution. Do not edit files under `/usr` except under `/usr/local`. Your changes will be overridden by the package manager.

If you want to use a different thousands separator, set `LC_NUMERIC` to a different value.

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 printf %\'.1f\\n 1000
$ 1,000.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the warning. But I cannot search all LC's to find an exact match. Even worse. As you say if that specific LC change in the future I have to find another.